# Unknown https call from my computer

Tags: http, https, fiddler

I captured weird call history from Fiddler.

The call repeatedly occurred.

I searched it with several keywords, but there were no clues.

Anyone know about this?

[image]

CNT https://1 CON 216
    Context: 67bc
    Last-Msg-Id: 0

```
------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 231
Context: 6402
Last-Msg-Id: 159d428c446a5b3e




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 216
Context: 61ce
Last-Msg-Id: 0




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 231
Context: 5dc2
Last-Msg-Id: 159d428c446a5b3e




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 216
Context: 5be6
Last-Msg-Id: 0




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 231
Context: 581c
Last-Msg-Id: 159d428c446a5b3e




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 216
Context: 5642
Last-Msg-Id: 0




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 231
Context: 52bd
Last-Msg-Id: 159d428c446a5b3e




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 216
Context: 5156
Last-Msg-Id: 0




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 231
Context: 4da3
Last-Msg-Id: 159d428c446a5b3e




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 216
Context: 4cce
Last-Msg-Id: 0




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 231
Context: 4912
Last-Msg-Id: 159d428c446a5b3e




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 216
Context: 48c3
Last-Msg-Id: 0




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 231
Context: 4510
Last-Msg-Id: 159d428c446a5b3e




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 216
Context: 44f3
Last-Msg-Id: 0




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 231
Context: 4171
Last-Msg-Id: 159d428c446a5b3e




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 216
Context: 4164
Last-Msg-Id: 0




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 231
Context: 3e64
Last-Msg-Id: 159d428c446a5b3e




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 216
Context: 3e5e
Last-Msg-Id: 0




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 231
Context: 3bee
Last-Msg-Id: 159d428c446a5b3e




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 216
Context: 3bee
Last-Msg-Id: 0




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 231
Context: 39e7
Last-Msg-Id: 159d428c446a5b3e




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 216
Context: 39e7
Last-Msg-Id: 0




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 216
Context: 39dd
Last-Msg-Id: 0




------------------------------------------------------------------

CNT https://1 CON 231
Context: 39dd
Last-Msg-Id: 159d428c446a5b3e




------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Which application/process is running when this weird HTTP request is captured?

Comment: @ELaRoche The weired are the red calls in the pictures.

Comment: @shaochuancs I didn't know Fiddler provides the process information. I confirmed that the call is coming from OneDrive app. Thanks guys :)

Comment: I would use Wireshark to dig a little deeper.  I have been using Fiddler for years and have not encountered your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I've seen this before, coming from the Windows Explorer process. It's harmless, but basically what's happening is the client is trying to send non HTTP traffic through a HTTPS proxy tunnel, and because it's not legal HTTPS traffic, you get the weird parsing errors as shown in your screenshot.

Sadly, I don't remember my findings about what specific Windows feature causes this. See the `wnpconnmanager.cpp` remark at https://github.com/cvandeplas/plaso/blob/master/test_data/skydriveerr.log, maybe this is from the Windows Notification Service?